# gfortran can't find OpenMP library (omp_lib.mod) under MinGW

Tags: windows, fortran, mingw, openmp, gfortran

I'm trying to compile a Fortran code that someone has sent me. It compiles fine on my Linux box, now I'm trying to compile it under MinGW on Windows. But when I run the `gfortran` command to compile and link it, it fails with the following error:

```
undumag_main_omp.f:8175:9:

       use omp_lib
         1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'omp_lib.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I'm using the `-fopenmp` switch to use OpenMP.

I've installed MinGW (5.3.0) using the Installation Manager, selecting the **mingw32-base** and **mingw32-gcc-fortran** packages. Are there other packages I should install for OpenMP compatibility? Or do I need to compile the `omp_lib.mod` file myself, and if so how? I can see that I have some `libgomp.*` files in my `MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0` folder, but there is no `omp_lib_mod` file anywhere.

Comment: Did you check the configure options by gfortran -v ? If it doesn't show --enable-libgomp you will need a copy which does.  Although libgomp doesn't have full support for windows, many pre-built compilers include it.

Comment: Yes, it does have that flag.