# gfortran can't find OpenMP library (omp_lib.mod) using MinGW

Tags: windows, fortran, mingw, openmp, gfortran

I am trying to compile a Fortran code including OpenMP. I am replicating the use of OpenMP from a different code. It built successfully once yesterday and then the next time I built it I get the following error:

```
../MAXBRG3D.f90:3:4:

 USE OMP_LIB      ! USED WITH OMP FUNCTIONS
    1
 Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'omp_lib.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
subdir.mk:329: recipe for target 'MAXBRG3D.o' failed
make: *** [MAXBRG3D.o] Error 1
```

The only changes I made to the code where to comment out a few sections of code unrelated to the OpenMP capabilities. I have since removed the comments but am still getting the same error. My compilation command is as follows.

```
gfortran -funderscoring -O0 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fopenmp -o "MAXBRG3D.o" "../MAXBRG3D.f90"
```

I have seen the following link: [gfortran can't find OpenMP library (omp_lib.mod) under MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630301/gfortran-cant-find-openmp-library-omp-lib-mod-under-mingw)
and when I run `gfortran -v, --enable-libgomp` does show up.

```
>gfortran -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
```

I was able to run the following little Fortran code.

```
PROGRAM TEST
  INTEGER M
  REAL C(3), D(3)

  M=3
  C(1) = 2
  C(2) = 5
  C(3) = 10
  call A1(M,C,D)
  write(*,5)D(3)
  5 format(1x,'D3=',G12.5)
END PROGRAM

SUBROUTINE A1(N, A, B)
  INTEGER I, N
  REAL B(N), A(N)
!$OMP PARALLEL DO !I is private by default
  DO I=2,N
    B(I) = (A(I) + A(I-1)) / 2.0
  ENDDO
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
END SUBROUTINE A1
```

Also I do have libgomp.a, libgomp.dll.a, libgomp.spec, (located in MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0) and libgomp-1.dll (located in MinGW\bin).

Comment: Where did you get your gfortran from? Do you use Cygwin? What does `gfortran -v` print?

Comment: Please try to compile a simple OpenMP Hello world program which does not use the `omp_lib` module. Please report what happens. Is there any file called `libgomp*` in your computer (among other GCC and gfortran libraries)?

Comment: I am using MinGW on windows. I am not using Cygwin.

Comment: Also show the *exact* gfortran command that generated the error message. We need to see `-fopenmp` but better the whole exact command.

Comment: I am not even sure that module file should exist and I can't check now. If yes, then copying it from other gfortran of the same version could help (or not).

Comment: In my Linux computer the module file is located at `(/usr/local/)gcc-5.3/lib64/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/finclude/omp_lib.mod`. It might be worth to get the mod file from a different installation of the gcc 6.3.0 version and try to use it. Not guaranteed to help, but worth a try IMO. I assume you have already checked that you don't have this file in your computer.

Comment: I did check that I don't have that file

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. I commented out the `USE OMP_LIB` line and I just initialized the functions that I wanted to use.

Previously I found an example which initialized the functions as

```
INTEGER FUNCTION OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
```

This was not working. However I found a different example which initialized the functions just as integers. So

```
INTEGER OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM
```

This seems to have solved the problem and now the code is compiling and running.

Comment: In Fortran, it's USE omp_lib  with .mod being implied.   As you quoted it it would want omp_lib.mod.mod.  you may need to set -I (capital I) to point the include directory of your compiler.

Comment: @tim18 That is probably just a typo here, look at the error message.

Comment: Using an implicit interface is indeed a possibility which I thought about. It is rather a workaround, not a full solution. It makes your code worse and will be painful with 3rd party codes. But if it is sufficient for you, then you are fine.