# OpenMP Not compiling on gFortran (MinGW)

Tags: fortran, mingw, openmp, gfortran

My problem is similar to this ([gfortran can't find OpenMP library (omp_lib.mod) using MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849793/gfortran-cant-find-openmp-library-omp-lib-mod-using-mingw)). However, no one seems to solve this and I am stuck trying to figure this out. And yes I already have libgomp installed which I reinstall and also double check in my C:/MinGW folder. Can someone help me to resolve this? Why can't my gFortran compiler open the module omp_lib? Otherwise, my compiler works fine as long as I don't use OpenMP.

Here is the error shown,

```
use omp_lib
     1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'omp_lib.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: How are you compiling this program?  In particular, do you have the flag `-fopenmp`?

Comment: I am not sure how to use the fopen and i use this "gfortran -fopenmp 1st.f95". However, I still get the same error as above

Comment: My Fortran version is GNU Fortran (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5) 8.2.0

Comment: -fopenmp works as long as I don't use the command "use omp_lib". However, this is not what I want as I am using a code that already contains the implementation of 'use omp_lib' and I don't want to change the code by switching to -fopenmp

Comment: -fopenmp works as long as I don't use the command "use omp_lib". However, this is not what I want as I am using a code that already contains the implementation of 'use omp_lib' and I don't want to change the code by switching to -fopenmp

Comment: So you want to use OpenMP, but not the compiler-provided module `omp_lib`?  In which case you'd maybe want to try changing the source to have `use, non_intrinisic :: omp_lib`.  If that doesn't work then we'll need more detail on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am still new to these so I don't really how to phrase these in techical terms. I am trying to get my code to run using OpenMP using the gfortran compiler I download from the MinGW setup. I am testing using the simple Hello World code which contains the "use omp_lib" command. However, when I run it on my MinGW32 terminal using this command 'gfortran 1st.f95 -o 1st.exe', I get the error as shown in the original post. I am hoping to get past that error and successfully compile my code with the 'use omp_lib' command in it without incurring the above error

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the command "use, non_intrinisic :: omp_lib" suggested by you. I try typing that in my code and compile it using gfortran but I get an error stating "Module nature in USE statement at (1) shall be either INTRINSIC or NON_INTRINSIC
1st.f95:8:30:" and "Function 'omp_get_thread_num' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type"

Comment: Typo, should be `non_intrinsic` as suggested by the compiler's error message.  But it sounds like that's not what you want.  If `gfortran -fopenmp 1st.f95 -o 1st.exe` doesn't work, then there's something unfortunate happening.

Comment: Yes that is what I want but I can't find any answer out there. I try gfortran -v and check that --enable-libgomp is there. Likewise, mingw-get already shows that I installed libgomp. Do you know whether is there other package that I need to install? Or do you know where can I download the omp_lib.mod file so that I will try manually placing them into my folder

Comment: I think you should mention the INCLUDE directory. try ```-I"directory containig omp_lib module"```

Comment: Hi I tried ' gfortran 1st.f95 -I"directory containig omp_lib module" ' but I get an error stating 'Can't find an intrinsic module named 'omp_lib' at (1) compilation terminated.'