# OpenMP not found using MinGW / gfortran on Windows 10

Tags: windows, fortran, mingw, openmp, gfortran

I'm using GNU Fortran 9.2.0 with all latest updates and upgrades on Windows 10. I would like to compile a code that uses OpenMP.

Trying `gcc -v`, I see `--enable-libgomp`.

Trying to compile the code with `use OMP_LIB`, I'm experiencing the same error like reported [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60378271/openmp-not-compiling-on-gfortran-mingw?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Very similar questions have already been raised earlier:

- [gfortran can't find OpenMP library using MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849793/gfortran-cant-find-openmp-library-omp-lib-mod-using-mingw)
- [gfortran can't find OpenMP library under MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630301/gfortran-cant-find-openmp-library-omp-lib-mod-under-mingw)

As in none of these questions a viable solution was provided, I'm raising this again.

Comment: Did you use `-fopenmp` at all? Show us your exact compilation command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC 9.2.0 is outdated, current version is 13.2.0.

Try with a more recent MinGW-w64 GCC build, for example from https://winlibs.com/

Comment: Does GCC 9.2.0 on MinGW no longer support OpenMP?

Comment: I suppose it was supported back then, but they kept improving OpenMP support in GCC, so I don't see why you would stick with a version that is 4 years old.

Comment: Thank you Brecht for the advice.
This solved my problem with OMP_LIB (although another issue occurs now with the code).